# Declare a struct in C without defining it

Tags: c, struct, declaration

I'd like to declare a struct in C without defining it at the same time (i.e. to separate interface and implementation) so others can include this in their projects and define it to their needs (it is only used as a parameter in my code). Thus, I'd like to know if this is:

A) Possible (maybe just using macros)?

B) Considered good practise (in my particular circumstance)?

B would be hard to answer without context (and is still subjective) so I'd only like it examined against any common pre-existing patterns in C for addressing the given context (if any). I have the following code:

```
typedef struct {
    bool logged_in;
} Foo;
```

That I would like as this (pseudo code):

```
typedef struct Foo;
```

So this declaration can then be defined by the person who is including this in their project. In my code I am only using it as a parameter without trying to access the properties it contains, like so:

```
bool bar(Foo* foo) {
    //...
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `struct Foo;` should be enough as a forward declaration.

Comment: Define it in a header file  **foo.h**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forward-declare it like this:

```
typedef struct Foo Foo;
```

Then define it with it's ‘full name’:

```
struct Foo {
    …
};
```

Or you can just forward-declare the ‘full name’:

```
struct Foo;
```

And use that:

```
bool bar(struct Foo *foo) {
    …
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you that was fast. Ok I'll give that a go when I'm back at my computer (can't check to mark answered at the moment)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try it?  This compiles for me with no warnings on GCC:

```
typedef struct Foo_ Foo;

int bar( Foo *foop )
{
    return 1;
}
```

I don't know any reason why you wouldn't want to do it.

Comment: Thank you, shall give that a go also